# Replacing element in XSLT results in wrapper element to occur twice (Saxon)

Tags: html, xslt, saxon

I am experiencing some weird behaviour trying to process a chunk of HTML with XSLT. I am trying to replace an img element with a figure element. The element is replaced, but the surrounding wrapper element then appears twice, once before the figure element, and once after. The example below illustrates the problem. The problem exists in both Saxon 9.0.0.8 and 9.1.0.8 (two different versions of our CMS)

The HTML I am processing is as follows:

```
    <p class="editor-p-block">
      <img alt="Untitled-2" src="image://11?_size=full" title="Untitled-2" />
    </p>
```

The templates are as follows:

```
<xsl:template name="stk:html.process">
    <xsl:param name="document" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$document/*|$document/text()" mode="html.process"/>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element()" mode="html.process">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*" mode="html.process"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="img" mode="html.process">
   <xsl:element name="figure"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="html.process">
   <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
    <p class="editor-p-block">         
    </p>
    <figure></figure>
    <p></p>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Full reproducable example:

```
<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="document" as="element()">
        <content xmlns="">
            <p class="editor-p-block">
                <img alt="Untitled-2" src="image://11?_size=full" title="Untitled-2"/>
            </p>
        </content>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="stk:html.process">
        <xsl:with-param name="document" select="$document"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="stk:html.process">
    <xsl:param name="document" as="element()"/>
    <div class="editor">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$document/*|$document/text()" mode="html.process"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element()" mode="html.process">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*" mode="html.process"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="img" mode="html.process">
    <xsl:element name="figure"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="html.process">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Consider to post small but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. Where do you call `stk:html.process`, if at all? Which is the context node, where do you set the parameter?

Comment: Ok, this is a fully reproducable example:

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem, using Saxon 9.5 HE Java and the following samples:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:stk="http://example.com/so">

<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="document" as="element()">
        <content xmlns="">
            <p class="editor-p-block">
                <img alt="Untitled-2" src="image://11?_size=full" title="Untitled-2"/>
            </p>
        </content>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="stk:html.process">
        <xsl:with-param name="document" select="$document"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="stk:html.process">
    <xsl:param name="document" as="element()"/>
    <div class="editor">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$document/*|$document/text()" mode="html.process"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element()" mode="html.process">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*" mode="html.process"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="img" mode="html.process">
    <xsl:element name="figure"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="html.process">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

run against any input XML I get the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div xmlns:stk="http://example.com/so" class="editor">
   <p class="editor-p-block">
      <figure></figure>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The CMS I am using is using Saxon 9.0.0.8, the problem also exists in a newer version using 9.1.0.8.

Comment: I have just tried the above sample with Saxon 9.1.0.8 B, the output is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div xmlns:stk="http://example.com/so" class="editor">
   <p class="editor-p-block">
      <figure></figure>
   </p>
</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce the problem using Saxon outside your CMS? If not, the finger points to your CMS...

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, I have found the explanation to this problem. It isn't related to the XSLT processing at all.

It turns out that the HTML standard does not allow you to put a figure element inside a p element. A p element can only contain so called "phrasing content", which includes the following elements:

```
<abbr>, <audio>, <b>, <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>, <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <progress>, <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>, <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <var>, <video>, <wbr> and plain text (not only consisting of white spaces characters).
```

Thus, the browser developer tools used in my test just moved the element outside, and for some reason also creates a duplicate wrapper element.
If I replace figure with i.e. img or strong, the problem vanishes.